# How can i make git keep another branch files

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches A, B

I want to merge B with A

new files should be added.

But if files are chnaged in both , then i want to keep files from B . But git is auto merging them

I am using this

```
git checkout A
git merge -xtheirs B
```

Comment: Does that work? Are you looking for something like http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html ?

Comment: it does not work , The conflicting files are ok but the issue is with files which git automerges

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet is to temporarily create a .gitattributes file that declares everything to be binary or that everything should use the "binary" merge driver. Then do the git merge, then git add all conflicted files to mark them resolved, and git commit. [[Don't forget to reset/remove the temp .gitattributes file afterwards.]]

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

```
Built-in merge drivers
...
binary
Keep the version from your branch in the work tree, but
leave the path in the conflicted state for the user to sort out.
```